# Delete memory allocated in C# in C++ code

Tags: c#, c++, memory-management, interop

I have codes interop between C# (core) and C++ (unmanaged DLL).

Memory allocated in C# using `Marshal.AllocHGlobal()` needs to be released in C# using `Marshal.FreeHGlobal()`.

Memory allocated in C++ using `new` needs to be released in C++ using `delete`.

Can I just `delete` or `FreeHGlobal()` whenever I wish, since the GC is no longer tracing these memory handler?

Comment: No, they track memory allocations separately. One does not know about the other.

Comment: I just found out that in dotnet core 3.0, I can actually pass the C# byte[] directly to C++ without using **Marshal.AllocHGlobal()**.

Comment: @sk that is nothing new, .NET has always been able to do that. Read up on how PInvoke and marshaling actually work.

Answer (score 5):

No, you cannot just use whatever method you want to free memory.  You MUST use whatever the allocator *requires* you to use.  Only the memory manager that allocates a given block of memory knows how to free that block of memory properly.

For instance, the documentation for [`Marshal.AllocHGlobal()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.allochglobal) states:

> **This method exposes the Win32 LocalAlloc function from Kernel32.dll**.
>
> **When AllocHGlobal calls LocalAlloc, it passes a LMEM_FIXED flag**, which causes the allocated memory to be locked in place. Also, the allocated memory is not zero-filled.

And the documentation for [`LocalAlloc()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-localalloc) states:

> **To free the memory, use the LocalFree function**. It is not safe to free memory allocated with LocalAlloc using GlobalFree.

Which is what [`Marshal.FreeHGlobal()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.freehglobal) uses:

> **FreeHGlobal exposes the LocalFree function from Kernel32.DLL**, which frees all bytes so that you can no longer use the memory pointed to by hglobal.

So, it is allowed for C# code to allocate memory using `Marshal.AllocHGlobal()` and then for C++ code to free that memory using `LocalFree()`. And conversely, for C++ code to allocate memory using `LocalAlloc(LMEM_FIXED)` and then for C# code to free that memory using `Marshal.FreeHGlobal()`.

Likewise, the `Marshal` class also has a [`Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.alloccotaskmem) method:

> **This method exposes the COM CoTaskMemAlloc function**, which is referred to as the COM task memory allocator.

Memory allocated by [`CoTaskMemAlloc()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-cotaskmemalloc) is freed with [`CoTaskMemFree()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-cotaskmemfree):

> Frees a block of task memory previously allocated through a call to the CoTaskMemAlloc or CoTaskMemRealloc function.

Which is what [`Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.freecotaskmem) uses :

> **FreeCoTaskMem exposes the COM CoTaskMemFree function**, which frees all bytes so that you can no longer use the memory that the ptr parameter points to.

So, it is allowed for C# code to allocate memory using `Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem()` and then for C++ code to free that memory using `CoTaskMemFree()`. And conversely, for C++ code to allocate memory using `CoTaskMemAlloc()` and then for C# code to free that memory using `Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem()`.

Now, that being said, the memory manager that C++ uses for its `new` and `delete` operators is *implementation-defined*. There is no guarantee (or likelihood) that `new` uses `LocalAlloc()` or `CoTaskMemAlloc()`, or that `delete` uses `LocalFree()` or `CoTaskMemFree()`.

So, it is not legal for C# to free any memory allocated with `new`, or for C++ to `delete` any memory allocated by C#.

Comment: Thanks for the detail info, that is very helpful. I do aware that C++ new / delete will actually call the constructor / destructor, which in turns will new / delete more memory. I am referring to basic memory pointer here.

Comment: @sk it is more complicated than that. Even with basic data types, you still can't mismatch allocations and deallocations. There are other factors at play that I didn't describe.